# Is there a standard way to configure what policy iptables loads on startup under Debian?

Tags: debian, security, iptables, init-script

I've just started playing with Debian 6.0 (Squeeze) in a VPS environment, as a way to learn more about system administration.

One thing I'd like to configure is a default packet filtering policy. (Permit new and established SSH inbound, permit rate limited ICMP inbound, drop everything else inbound, permit anything outbound, etc etc)

I've determined how to build a policy which roughly meets my needs, however there doesn't seem to be an existing init script which specifies where iptables should load its policy from on startup. Is there a standard way to do this on Debian?

I've seen various alternatives suggested, all of which seem to involve creating a shell script somewhere somewhere and invoking it in RC scripts, initscripts, `/etc/network/interfaces`...

Is there no 'blessed' way to do this in Debian? It seems like a fairly glaring oversight.

Comment: I think the /etc/network/interfaces is the most "debian way" of doing this. Some distributions have init scripts by default which save and load iptables rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no default standart way to setup a firewall in Debian, except maybe calling a script with a `pre` rule in the network configuration (`/etc/network/interfaces`) but there are many packages providing different ways to do it.

For example the packages [uruk](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/uruk) and [iptables-persistent](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/iptables-persistent) provide very simple scripts to load and backup a very simple firewall.

Comment: I ended up putting a script in /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ - accepting this answer since 'there is no default' is correct.